# How to separate mysql row values by comma using php?

Tags: php, mysql, string

I have tried the following code to output each student `father_contact` by firstly merging them and secondly separating each number by comma and could not make it working. Please help me.

```
$sql = "SELECT Fathers_Contact FROM student WHERE Class ='$class' AND Section='$s' and Year='$y'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
    die("Query not working");
} 

$mbno_arr = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $mbno_arr[] = $row[0];
}

$mbno_list = implode(',', $mbno_arr);//expect here is: 9867656543,9867656443,9867654543

if(empty($mbno_list)){
    echo "No number is there";
    exit;
}

if(empty($msg)){
    echo "Message empty!";
    exit;
}
```

Father_contact is ten digit mobile no.

Comment: "*It is not working*" is not useful. Please explain, if you get an error message (if so, which one) or if the results differ from your expectation (if so, how).

Comment: @AMAL Murali, I will update it with abit more codes

Comment: @Hanner we can see the code, but what exactly isn't working?

Comment: @Latheesan Kanes, In the database, in Fathers_contact field I put three mobile numbers. But No number is there is the error message I got.

Comment: You should place an echo in your while loop to check if it has value, and runs. You can also do `print_r($mbno_arr);` after your while to see if there are any valus in the array before you implode

Comment: @LatheesanKanes, I am checking. In my table in Fathers_Contact field, I have 20 rows, of which only three rows have Fathers_Contact field filled and the remaining null. So, can that be the problem? I am still trying with your codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement
$SQL = sprintf(
        "SELECT Fathers_Contact 
         FROM student 
         WHERE Class = '%s' AND Section = '%s' and Year = '%s'", 
        mysql_real_escape_string($class), 
        mysql_real_escape_string($s), 
        mysql_real_escape_string($y)
);

// Result or die (print mysql error)
$result = mysql_query($SQL) or die( mysql_error() );

// Check if result has rows
if( mysql_numrows($result) > 0 )
{
    $mbno_arr = array();

    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) )
        $mbno_arr[] = $row[0];

    if( count($mbno_arr) > 0)
        echo implode(',', $mbno_arr);
    else
        echo 'No number is there';
}
else
{
    echo 'No result for query';
}

// free result
mysql_free_result($result);
```

**NB** use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). mysql_* is deprecated

Comment: one more problem, if some rows are null, how do I escape them? AS of this code, it does not escape, so they look like ,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: Ok, I edited the code and added is not null and now it is working fine. Thanks any way.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `mysql_*` is now officially deprecated. Please use `PDO` or `MySQLi`.

Can you try this:

```
<?php

// Connect
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_database");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

// Query
$query = "SELECT Fathers_Contact FROM student WHERE Class = ? AND Section = ? and Year = ?";
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
{
    // Bind params
    $stmt->bind_param("sss",
        $class,
        $s,
        $y);

    // Execute statement
    $stmt->execute();

    // fetch associative array
    $mbno_arr = array();
    $result = $stmt->fetch_result();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        // Build data
        $mbno_arr[] = $row['Fathers_Contact'];
    }

    // close statement
    $stmt->close();

    // Debug?
    $mbno_list = implode(',', $mbno_arr);
    if (empty($mbno_list)) {
        echo "No number is there";
    } else {
        echo "Query Results: $mbno_list";
    }
}

// Close Connection
$mysqli->close();

?>
```

Comment: Suggesting mysqli isnt a solution. Though I agree that updating is a good thing, it should be a note in an answer, not the answer. There might be reasons mysqli is not an option